# Google Sheets - Dependent drop-down lists

Tags: drop-down-menu, google-apps-script

I am recreating and expanding on a doc I had previously made. I have already brought in the script I had used originally, and tweaked it where I believed appropriate to get it working in this sheet, but I must have missed something. Editable samples of the 3 spreadsheet files involved can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B1-BYilDJaZMdnhVdDJKUmVUamM?usp=sharing). These files are a sample "Price List", "Catalog"(which aggregates manufacturer names from all price lists, and also has a "Catalog" tab for misc items not sold by one of my primary vendors), and "Addendum B" which is the file I require assistance with.

This document is an addendum to my contracts which lists all equipment being sold as part of that contract. It has 2 sheets in it ("Addendum B" and "XREF"), and "Addendum B" has several dependent columns: Vendor, Manufacturer, Model, Description, and Price. Their dependencies are as follows:

*Currently Working*

- Vendor: Basic data validation pulling from XREF!A2:A.

*Not working, script in file*

- Manufacturer: Based on the Vendor selected, should be a drop-down
  list generated from the column headed with that vendor's name on
  "XREF".

*Now here's were it gets tricky beyond what I had previously done.*

- Model: I want this column to be a drop-down listing all model numbers
  associated with that manufacturer, from a completely separate price
  list provided to me by my vendor. (I have shared a sample price list which reflects column positions as they appear in all such files.
- Description: Displays the corresponding description for the Model selected, from the price list selected in the Vendor column.
- Price: Displays the corresponding markup price for the Model selected, from the price list selected in the Vendor column.

And that about summarizes my goals and what I'm struggling with.

Comment: Final note, you will get a better response if you include your code and restrict yourself from asking multiple questions. Including code shows you put effort into the problem and asking just one/related question keeps the problem tractable. Also, prevents the question from getting closed for being too board.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I looked into your script file in sheet Addendum B.
I have made few edits and it should be working now, the modified code:

```
    function onEdit() 
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
      sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(),
      name = sheet.getName();
  if (name != 'Addendum B') return;
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange(),
      col = range.getColumn();
  if (col != 6) return;  //You col was set to 5 changed it to 6!
  var val = range.getValue(),
      dv = ss.getSheetByName('XREF'),
      data = dv.getDataRange().getValues(),
      catCol = data[0].indexOf(val),
      list = [];
  Logger.log(catCol)
  for (var i = 1, len = 100; i < len; i++) // Problem is here, you have too many items in list! Cannot have more 500 items for validation
      list.push(data[i][catCol]);
  var listRange = dv.getRange(2,catCol +1,dv.getLastRow() - 1, 1)
  Logger.log(list)
  var cell = sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), col-1)
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
  .requireValueInRange(listRange)   // Use requireValueIn Range instead to fix the problem
  .build();
  cell.setDataValidation(rule);
  Logger.log(cell.getRow())
}
```

The reason your validation was not working was you had more than 500 items in your data validation list. I just modified it to take the same values from range instead. Hope you find that helpful!

Now for the remaining 3 questions, here are my comments and thoughts on it:

1) I didn't find any code related to the problem you mentioned in your question. So, I am gonna assume you are asking for general ideas on how to achieve this?

2) You basically approach the problem the same as you did with the above code! Once a manufacturer is selected, the script looks for that manufacturer in the sheet and update the Data validation in the corresponding model column.
You will modify the code like so

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1nbCJOkpIQxnn71sJPj6X4KaahROP5cMg1SI9xIeJdvY")
//The above code with select the catalog sheet.
dv = ss.getSheetByName('Misc_Catalog')
//The above code will open the Misc_Catalog tab.
```

3) A better approach would be to use Sidebar/Dialog Box to validate your input then add it to the sheet at the end. (Looks Cleaner and also prevents unnecessary on edit trigger in the sheet, which can take a while to update.) 
You find more details here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs

Comment: That's interesting. I'm not familiar with creating either of those. You're suggesting a dialog box that contains three drop-downs, and then on 'OK' it populates the row?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The dropdown will get updated as you fill in the required details.

Comment: So, I was just testing your fix, and it doesn't seem to be working completely. The Manufacturer drop-down is only showing the first 48 results. 

As for the dialog box/sidebar, could you give me an example of how I would stack all that code? I reviewed the link you provided at the end of your answer, and understand the general principals at work, but this is just outside my familiarity.

Comment: Yeah was using the wrong sheet to get the last row. Modified it, it should work now.

Comment: Thank you again for your invaluable assistance. I'm still unsure of how to write the second lookup. In a cell formula I would use '=arrayformula(vlookup(...))', but I don't know how to translate that into this scenario. The first drop-down was retrieving a defined list from a column, but the Model drop-down needs to find all values of colB where colA=MFR.

Comment: You can use probably use =filter(). All the best.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was unclear. My problem is I'm not sure how to change the `var ListRange =` line to include the filter. Can I insert a CategoryFilter defined against my other spreadsheet, or do i need to define my data as a table and then filter the table, and feed that into the `listRange` argument?

Comment: You will have to go through each value and pick out the values that you want. Then select the corresponding range, write a brief code to do the same with a sample dataset. Perfect it there, then include it to this code. Also please start a new thread if you have further questions and do include your code. That way more people will be able to assist you with that. Comments are not a good way to get answers or communicate in this forum.